# R: apply function to each row of a data frame by factor, calling in the function a value (by factor)

Tags: r, apply

I have a big dataset like this:

```
my.df <- data.frame(Cond= rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 4),
             Gene = rep(c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4"), 4),
             Avg=sample(85:100, 16, replace = TRUE), 
             SE=sample(1:5, 16, replace = TRUE), 
             Val1=sample(1:50, 16),
             Val2=sample(1:50, 16))
```

Now, for each gene, I want to normalize everything (divide each value of "Avg", "SE", "Val1" and "Val2" by) the Avg value for Cond A.

My current idea is to do something like this:

```
by(my.df[ , 3:6], Gene,   #since I want to do my calculation on each Gene
   lapply(function(x)   #since I want to do my calculation on each value
```

but I don't know how to write the function so that it takes the current value of `x` and divides it by the Cond A Avg value for that Gene.

Alternatively, it occurred to me to make another data frame containing the Gene and Cond A Avg values:

```
CondAavg <- my.df[Cond =="A", c("Gene","Avg")]
```

and then try to use sapply to apply a function to each value of "Gene", but I'm not quite seeing how to make that work, either.

I'm obviously still pretty new to R, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in 2 steps , using `merge`:

```
dtm = merge(subset(my.df,Cond!='A'),
     subset(my.df,Cond=='A',select=c('Gene','Avg')),by='Gene')
   Gene Cond Avg.x SE Val1 Val2 Avg.y
1  Gene1    B    97  4    9   29    88
2  Gene1    C    97  5   30   21    88
3  Gene1    D    94  5   19   39    88
4  Gene2    B    88  2   13   20    97
5  Gene2    C    98  5   20   43    97
6  Gene2    D    95  4   39    2    97
7  Gene3    B    93  5   40   50    89
8  Gene3    C    92  5   43   30    89
9  Gene3    D    91  3   27   11    89
10 Gene4    B    87  2   49   49    98
11 Gene4    C    97  3    6   47    98
12 Gene4    D    88  3   33   44    98
```

Then I divide numeric columns by the last one:

```
  dtm[,c(3:6)] <- dtm[,c(3:6)]/dtm[,'Avg.y']

   Gene Cond     Avg.x         SE       Val1       Val2 Avg.y
1  Gene1    B 1.1022727 0.04545455 0.10227273 0.32954545    88
2  Gene1    C 1.1022727 0.05681818 0.34090909 0.23863636    88
3  Gene1    D 1.0681818 0.05681818 0.21590909 0.44318182    88
4  Gene2    B 0.9072165 0.02061856 0.13402062 0.20618557    97
5  Gene2    C 1.0103093 0.05154639 0.20618557 0.44329897    97
6  Gene2    D 0.9793814 0.04123711 0.40206186 0.02061856    97
7  Gene3    B 1.0449438 0.05617978 0.44943820 0.56179775    89
8  Gene3    C 1.0337079 0.05617978 0.48314607 0.33707865    89
9  Gene3    D 1.0224719 0.03370787 0.30337079 0.12359551    89
10 Gene4    B 0.8877551 0.02040816 0.50000000 0.50000000    98
11 Gene4    C 0.9897959 0.03061224 0.06122449 0.47959184    98
12 Gene4    D 0.8979592 0.03061224 0.33673469 0.44897959    98
```

Better to use `grep` to avoid numeric indexing:

```
dtm[, !grepl('Gene|Cond',names(dtm))] = 
    dtm[, !grepl('Gene|Cond',names(dtm))] /dtm[,'Avg.y']
> dtm
    Gene Cond     Avg.x         SE       Val1       Val2 Avg.y
1  Gene1    B 1.1022727 0.04545455 0.10227273 0.32954545     1
2  Gene1    C 1.1022727 0.05681818 0.34090909 0.23863636     1
3  Gene1    D 1.0681818 0.05681818 0.21590909 0.44318182     1
4  Gene2    B 0.9072165 0.02061856 0.13402062 0.20618557     1
5  Gene2    C 1.0103093 0.05154639 0.20618557 0.44329897     1
6  Gene2    D 0.9793814 0.04123711 0.40206186 0.02061856     1
7  Gene3    B 1.0449438 0.05617978 0.44943820 0.56179775     1
8  Gene3    C 1.0337079 0.05617978 0.48314607 0.33707865     1
9  Gene3    D 1.0224719 0.03370787 0.30337079 0.12359551     1
10 Gene4    B 0.8877551 0.02040816 0.50000000 0.50000000     1
11 Gene4    C 0.9897959 0.03061224 0.06122449 0.47959184     1
12 Gene4    D 0.8979592 0.03061224 0.33673469 0.44897959     1
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's a lot simpler than what I was trying, and definitely gets the job done.  It did occur to me as a solution, but I didn't know how to use merge to make the final column.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: note this was a misinterpretation of what the OP asked.  What this does is normalize every column in the data frame by its average for `Cond=="A"`.  Leaving it here in case someone cares about that.  Thanks Agstudy.

You can try:

```
norm.vec <- colMeans(subset(my.df, Cond=="A")[-(1:2)])
my.df[-(1:2)] <- t(t(my.df[-(1:2)]) / norm.vec)
```

This takes advantage of recycling (but we need to transpose for it to work). `head(df)`:

```
#    Cond  Gene       Avg        SE       Val1      Val2
# 1     A Gene1 0.9470752 0.6153846 0.89655172 1.6752137
# 2     A Gene2 1.0473538 1.2307692 1.41379310 0.5811966
# 3     A Gene3 1.0473538 1.5384615 0.44827586 1.6068376
# 4     A Gene4 0.9582173 0.6153846 1.24137931 0.1367521
# 5     B Gene1 1.0250696 0.3076923 0.06896552 0.6495726
# 6     B Gene2 0.9582173 1.2307692 0.41379310 0.4444444
```

Comment: @Brodgie this is what the OP is looking for. No need to use `colMeans`  even I think that this can be an excellent solution! You should just take the `Avg` column to construct norm.vec.

Comment: @agstudy, LOL, thanks for giving me props for answering a question that was not asked.  I was totally thrown off by the name of the column!!  Given what is actually asked, I don't think this answer works unless I make a lot of assumptions about the order and number of genes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it using the `plyr` package:

```
library("plyr")

ddply(my.df, .(Gene), transform,
      Avg.norm = Avg / Avg[Cond=="A"],
      SE.norm = SE / SE[Cond=="A"],
      Val1.norm = Val1 / Val1[Cond=="A"],
      Val2.norm = Val2 / Val2[Cond=="A"])
```

I put the normalized values into new columns, but you could just as easily overwrite the existing ones.